# Redundant piece of code in parse APIs functions?

Tags: java, parsing, lucene, javacc

While studying some parsing APIs, I ran into a common technique used for writing the parse function:

```
final public Query parse() throws ParseException {
  Query q;
  // some parsing code using tokens here

  {if (true) return q;}
  throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");
}
```

I noticed that this same syntax is being used by many parser classes

(i.e. org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.parser.StandardSyntaxParser#TopLevelQuery &

http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r320/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonParser.java#parse
)

and it confuses me, because I can't come to a specific conclusion, why this piece of code is written like this.

Is there something hidden, besides emphasizing that it has to always return something?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That class has been autogenerated. From source code: `/* Generated By:JavaCC: Do not edit this line. JsonParser.java */`. I can't tell you *why* the authors of JavaCC chose to generate that useless condition though.  Maybe you can plug extra return conditions in before generating?  I'd also like to know why they chose to `throw Error` rather than leave the class with compile errors if no `return` ended up being generated. My guess is that this was generated from Javascript code, where the return statement is optional.  Translating into Java might necessitate this approach, but can't think why.

Comment: First the code wasn't written in the usual sense, it was generated as other have mentioned. The `throw` command is there because the code will not compile without it. At least the Eclipse compiler gives a fatal error. (Try deleting that line and see what happens.) The real question is why is the `if(true)` there, and for that I have no answer.  By the way this has nothing to do with emphasis, because you really shouldn't be reading this file except when there is a error that needs fixing. And it has nothing to do with JavaScript; JavaCC's input is a JavaCC grammar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autogenerated code is usually correct, but hardly ever looks elegant. It's difficult enough to generate correct code without worrying about elegance.

Plausible guesses: The { is there because at that point, the generator doesn't know whether it'll need it or not; it will learn soon but "soon" is not "now". The throw is there because at that point the generator isn't sure that it has generated a return statement for 100% of input.